# Prompt for Subject Line When Creating a New Email

Tags: vba, email, outlook, userform

I use 2007 Outlook.

I'm trying to get a code that upon creation of a new email prompts the user to pick one of the fixed radio button options as follows [A]: , [R]:, [F:] , [!]: , Blank (Option to get subject line blank).

I want that selection to be inserted into the subject line automatically.

I found code online but it errors out towards the end of the code.

```
Private Sub m_colInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
```

I pasted this code in the ThisOutlookSession module.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents m_colInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents CurrentInspector As Outlook.Inspector

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set m_colInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub CurrentInspector_Activate()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    If Len(UserForm1.SelectedSubject) Then
        Set oMail = CurrentInspector.CurrentItem
        oMail.Subject = UserForm1.SelectedSubject
    End If
    Set CurrentInspector = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub m_colInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.EntryID = vbNullString Then
        UserForm1.SelectedSubject = vbNullString
        UserForm1.Show
        Set CurrentInspector = Inspector
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I created a form with radio button and a command button where I inserted the following code.

```
Option Explicit
Public SelectedSubject As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        SelectedSubject = "Test"
    End If
    Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added Outlook-VBA as a tag for you.  There is no mention of Excel in your question so I assume that should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you want you want. Put it under `ThisOutlookSession`. When the user click on `Sends` this triggers, meaning they are not able to change the subject line before it is sent. I am using the `UserForm1` and the code you are using for that. Add as many radiobuttons as you like and just amend the `OptionButton1` to `2` and the value.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim strSubject As String
Dim Prompt$

    strSubject = Item.Subject
    ' Show RadioButtons
    UserForm1.Show
    ' Set Subject Line as the value from the selected RadioButton
    strSubject = UserForm1.SelectedSubject

    ' Set the message subject
    Item.Subject = strSubject
    strSubject = Item.Subject

    ' Test if Subject Line is empty
    If Len(Trim(strSubject)) = 0 Then
        Prompt$ = "Subject is Empty. Are you sure you want to send the Mail?"
        If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check for Subject") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Niclas.
I dropped the code as directed and prompts my form but it doesn't paste the selected option into the subject before sending. The subject line remains the same.

I'm sure the issue is with my form, I'm still learning VBA and maybe I didn't attach the values assigned to option button. Could you help dissect my form to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It worked for me, but I think you are right that the issue is with the naming of your userform compared to what is in the code above. So it shows your form and you can do the selection? And you are still using `SelectedSubject`?